Zsh Variadic Assignment
I want to be able to perform a "variadic assignment" in zsh.
I thought the following would work, but I get parse error near =("${(@)1}")'`:
variadic() {
  local a b
  (a, b)=("${(@)1}")
  echo "$a, $b!"
}

$ variadic Hello world  # Desired output: Hello, world!

(a, b)=($1 $2) results in a similar error.
Thank you

Where did you see anything saying zsh supports assignments like that?

(a, b) creates a subshell, in which zsh tries to run the commands a, and b. What makes you think that this would be a valid assignment statement?

I was trying to convey destructuring into an array type, my bad. Given that it is LHS it's not that far of a stretch in my opinion.

Multi-variable assignment is available in for loops in zsh, so one (unusual-looking) option is to use that and then bypass the loop body:
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

variadic() {
    local a b
    for a b; break
    print -r -- "$a, $b!"
}

variadic Hello world
#=> Hello, world!

variadic Hello world with extra words
#=> Hello, world!

variadic Hello
#=> Hello, !

The function above uses a shortened form of the for loop, and also uses the default list ($@).
This equivalent version has the full loop syntax:
variadicfull() {
    local a b
    for a b in "$@"; do
        break
    done
    print -r -- "$a, $b!"
}

A more conventional assignment also works:
nonvariadic() {
    local a=$1 b=$2
    print -r -- "$a, $b!"
}


Combining your first two examples yields an acceptable solution for me:
variadic() {
local a b
for a b in "$@"; break
echo "$a, $b!"
}
Cool stuff: thank you, I learned something today. Apologies for the formatting.

for a b ("$@"); break will also work.

Nice, even shorter! Thanks for this.
